# create button reset on image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

hello i have an image upload with image preview, when user upload image, a button remove show up for cancel that image(the image user upload) and switch to back to image default(for this case placeholder image), and the button remove got hidden because input file didnt have any value.
for now i success to show up the button when user upload. but when user click the remove. only the button remove got hidden, but the image still there. how to make the image back to placeholder when user click remove?

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".input-file").on("change", function(){
            if($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).parent().find(".image-upload-footer").css({"display": "none"});
            } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".image-upload-footer").css({"display": "block"});
            }
        });
        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $(this).closest(".image-upload").parent().find(".input-file").val("").trigger('change');
        }); 
    });
```

this is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uxsxuwzd/1/

thankyou

Comment: reset by updating the src value again:  $('#image_upload_preview1').attr('src', "old value here");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace this code in your functions. You should have to reset the selected src of input file.

This is for multiple  type of images in dimension.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#image_upload_preview1').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
  $("#inputFile1").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() { 
  function readURLs(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#image_upload_preview2').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
  $("#inputFile2").change(function () {
    readURLs(this);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".input-file").on("change", function(){
            if($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).parent().find(".image-upload-footer").css({"display": "none"});
            } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".image-upload-footer").css({"display": "block"});
            }
        });
        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $(this).closest(".image-upload").parent().find(".input-file").val("").trigger('change');
            
            var newImg=$(this).attr('custattr');
             
           $("#"+$(this).closest(".image-upload").parent().find(".img-responsive").attr('id')).attr("src",newImg);
        }); 
    });
```

```css
.image-upload-footer p{
 display: inline
}
.image-upload  input[type=file]{
    display: none;
}
.image-upload label{
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
.image-upload img{
 cursor: pointer;
}
.profileback .deleteThis{
 position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 21px;
    padding: 0;
}
.deleteThis span{
 color: #fff
}
.image-upload-footer{
 background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.87);
  margin-top: -6px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
.image-upload-footer button{
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.image-upload-footer button span,.image-upload-footer p{
 color: #fff ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="inputFile1">
      <img id="image_upload_preview1"  class="img-responsive mainPic" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
    </label>
    <input id="inputFile1" class="input-file" type="file"/>
    <div class="image-upload-footer" style="display:none">
      <button type="reset" custattr="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="btn btn-red reset">
        <span class="fa fa-times"aria-hidden="true">X</span>
      </button>
      <p>remove</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="image-upload">
  <label for="inputFile2">
    <img id="image_upload_preview2"  class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/746x728" alt=""/>
  </label>
  <input id="inputFile2" class="input-file" type="file"/>
  <div class="image-upload-footer" style="display:none">
    <button type="button" custattr="http://placehold.it/746x728" class="btn btn-red reset">
      <span class="fa fa-times"aria-hidden="true">X</span>
    </button>
    <p>remove</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is for one type of images dimension

```
 $(".reset").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".image-upload").parent().find(".input-file").val("").trigger('change');
   $("#"+$(this).closest(".image-upload").parent().find(".img-responsive").attr('id')).attr("src","http://placehold.it/350x150");
});
```

Comment: i have 2 different placeholder, how to create like that sir?

Comment: If you have only two type of variation then try with if condition. lets change snippet...

Comment: .i.e custom  attribute for button. we can create our own attribute. Just like id, name, class etc .. etc...

Comment: For more information about custom attribute please have a look this help : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml